# Character Pointers (allotted by new)

Tags: c++, string, pointers, new-operator, strcmp

I wrote the following code:

```
char *pch=new char[12];
char *f=new char[42];
char *lab=new char[20];
char *mne=new char[10];
char *add=new char[10];
```

If initially I want these arrays to be null, can't I do this:

```
*lab="\0";
*mne="\0";
and so on.....
```

And after that if I want to add some cstring to an empty array can't I check:

```
 if(strcmp(lab,"\0")==0)
 //then add cstring by *lab="cstring";
```

And if I can't do any of these things, please tell me the right way to do it...

Comment: Use C-string -> I laugh at your problems, for you brought them on yourself.

Comment: The right way to do it is usually to use `std::string`.  Have you considered that?

Comment: Using C strings in C++ - especially heap-allocated C strings - in 99% of cases is just masochism.

Comment: @MatteoItalia...if i use std::string(say  string str;) will i be able to do str=strtok(f," "); where f is a char *?

Comment: Never, ever use `strtok`.  Ever.  It's only there so old code compiles.  If you ever find `strtok` in old code, rewrite the code.  It's a landmine.

Answer (score 3):

In C++11, an easy way to initialize arrays is by using brace-initializers:

```
char * p = new char[100] { 0 };
```

The reasoning here is that all the missing array elements will be zero-initialized. You can also use explicit value-initialization (I think that's even allowed in C++98/03), which is zero-initalization for the primitive types:

```
char * q = new char[110]();
```

Comment: I wouldn't have put the C++11 answer first; it's likely to be irrelevant to the questioner at this point in time.

Comment: @Mark: I was confused at first and got it the wrong way round. After checking, I literally swapped the two standards around. Now I'm not sure if I should edit it, time is clearly on my side here :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB...my compiler isnt accepting char *p=new char[100](0)....so i am using the latter method...does this also initialize each element of the array to 0 i.e. '\0'...

Comment: @Avinash: You got it mixed up: either `char[100] {0}`, or `char[100]()`. What's you're compiler? Yes, everything will be zero.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, as DeadMG says, the correct way of doing this is using `std:string`:

```
std::string lab; // empty initially, no further initialization needed

if (lab.size() == 0) // string empty, note, very fast, no character comparison
    lab += "cstring"; // or even lab = "cstring", as lab is empty
```

Also, in your code, if you insist in using C strings, after the initialization, the correct checking for the empty string would be

```
if (*lab == '\0')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I agree with everybody else to use a `std::string` instead of character arrays the vast majority of the time.  Link for help is here: [C++ Strings Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string)

Now to directly answer your question as well:

```
*lab="\0";
*mne="\0";
and so on.....
```

This is wrong.  Assuming your compiler doesn't give you an error, you're not assigning the "null terminator" to those arrays, you're trying to assign the pointer value of where the `"\0"` string is to the first few memory locations where the char* is pointing to!  Remember, your variables are pointers, not strings.  If you're trying to just put a null-character at the beginning, so that `strlen` or other C-string functions see an "empty" string, do this: `*lab='\0';`  The difference is that with single-ticks, it denotes the character `\0` whereas with double, it's a string literal, which returns a pointer to the first element.  I hope that made sense.

Now for your second, again, you can't just "assign" like that to C-style strings.  You need to put each character into the array and terminate it correctly.  Usually the easiest way is with `sprintf`:

`sprintf(lab, "%s", "mystring");`

This may not make much sense, especially as I'm not dereferencing the pointer, but I'll walk you through it.  The first argument says to sprintf "output your characters to where this pointer is pointing."  So it needs the raw pointer.  The second is a format string, like `printf` uses.  So I'm telling it to use the first argument as a string.  And the 3rd is what I want in there, a pointer to another string.  This example would also work with `sprintf(lab, "mystring")` as well.

If you want to get into C-style string processing, you need to read some examples.  I'm afraid I don't even know where to look on the 'net for good examples of that, but I wish you good luck.  I'd highly recommend that you check out the C++ strings library though, and the `basic_string<>` type there.  That's typedef'd to just std::string, which is what you should use.